# Lodash compare/merge object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I need to compare/merge 2 objects with diferent structure using Lodash.

```
   data= [
      {
        "name": "EMPRESA",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "DESIGEMPRESA",
        "value": "CMIP"
      },
      {
        "name": "UTILIZADOR",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "CD_INDICADOR",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "DT_INI_INDICADOR",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "DT_INI",
        "value": "2017-12-13"
      },
      .....
    ]
```

and

```
dbcolsData={
  "EMPRESA": "",
  "UTILIZADOR": "paulo.figueiredo",
  "CD_INDICADOR": "",
  "DT_INI_INDICADOR": "",
  "DT_INI": "",
  "DT_FIM": ""
}
```

The question is how i can fill the values of `data` with the values of dbcolsData ?
Lets say put the values of `dbColsData` in `data`
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
_.forEach(data, function(object){
   object.value = dbcolsData[object.name];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (or lodash's `_.map()`) to iterate the `data`, and get the results from `dbcolsData`:

```js
var data = [{"name":"EMPRESA","value":""},{"name":"DESIGEMPRESA","value":"CMIP"},{"name":"UTILIZADOR","value":""},{"name":"CD_INDICADOR","value":""},{"name":"DT_INI_INDICADOR","value":""},{"name":"DT_INI","value":"2017-12-13"}];

var dbcolsData = {"EMPRESA":"","UTILIZADOR":"paulo.figueiredo","CD_INDICADOR":"","DT_INI_INDICADOR":"","DT_INI":"","DT_FIM":""};

var result = data.map(function(o) {
  return Object.assign({ data: dbcolsData[o.name] }, o);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce `data` to the `dbcolsData` structure :

```
var myData = data.reduce((o, nvO) => Object.defineProperty(o, nvO.name, {value: nvO.value}), {})
```

->

Now you can use lodash comparison functions like `_.isEqual` :

```
_.isEqual(myData, dbcolsData)
```